# Poll For Element Change in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I create a test entry at the beginning of my test, but sometimes it doesn't load by the time the page is accessed in the test.  Wanted to poll for the entry, and if not present reload the page then check again.  Tried using the recursive function example for `cy.get()` in the docs, but getting an error:

```
Error:       TypeError: move.find(...).contains is not a function
```

Function:

```
function pollForTestMove() {
            cy.get('div[class="consumer-name-wrap"]')
                .then((move) => {
                    if (
                        move.find('span')
                        .contains("test" + localStorage.getItem('randomNameString') + " user" + localStorage.getItem('randomNameString') + " (TEST)", { "matchCase": true })
                    )
                        return

                    cy.reload
                    pollForTestMove()
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this particular error, I think using `cy.wrap` should be enough:

```
cy.wrap(move).find('span')...
```

However, I don't think the code with the conditional test will work as you expect it to work. Please take a look at [Cypress documentation about conditional testing.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition)

Hope it helps. If you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. Then call in your page pollForElement(name of the text from the element)

```
pollForElement(name) {
var count = 0;

function pollElement() {
  return cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.text().includes(name)) {
      console.log('item has been found');
      return $body;
    }
    else {
      count += 1;
      cy.wait(2000);
      cy.reload();
      console.log('Polling for element...');
    }
    if(count === 10 ) {
      console.log('Element not found');
      assert.isFalse(true, 'Element not found')
    }
    return pollElement();
  });
 }
return pollElement();
}
```